# What kind of edits are counted in /users?tab=editors?

Tags: support, edits, users-page

I already commented on this issue in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81645/userstab-editors-puts-paid-to-editor-category-badge-queries-on-data-explorer). Compare all time number edits in [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) and the number of [strunk and white badges awarded](https://stats.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white). 16 people should have been awarded the badge, but only 5 are awarded. So it seems that reported number of edits possibly includes self-edits. Am I right? If it is so, is it feasible to include them? If it is not so, what kind of edits are included?

Comment: at the current moment it seems that the self-edits are included, so my question stands. Why self-edits should be included?

Comment: I noticed this as well. I think it counts self-edits, which I agree shouldn't be included.

Answer (score 7):

The only difference between the count used for `strunk & white` and the count on the editors tab is that the one in the editors tab **also** counts posts that were simply retagged.

So the count is higher. To sum it up, those are the edits which are included:

1. Editing questions (not your own, including tag-only edits aka retagging)
2. Editing answers (not your own)
3. Editing tag wiki (body or excerpt)

Community Wiki posts are also counted same way as ordinary posts. Suggested edits count only when approved.

I have mixed feelings about fixing this. I am tempted to leave as is cause you already get `strunk & white` progress in /review

Let me know how you feel about it in comments, can be swayed either way.