# When were the editors and voters tabs on the users page introduced?

Tags: discussion, tabs, users-page

I am trying to analyze StackOverflow users' decisions about whether to edit and vote on one another's posts. Thus, it is important for me to know when these actions became more visible because of the introduction of the editors and voters tabs.

Was the editors tab created at the same time as the redesign of the users page on March 1, 2011 (https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-users-page/) or at a different time?

Using the Wayback Machine, I found that the editors tab existed on April 1, 2011 (http://web.archive.org/web/20110401181720/https://stackoverflow.com/users) but the first few months of 2011 are missing snapshots of this page.

Also the blog says that the voting tab was created in May of 2011 (https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) but it also appears on the snapshot of the users page captured on April 1, 2011. Was the voters tab also introduced during the redesign?

Comment: Why is this important? The first mention of it can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81655/what-kind-of-edits-are-counted-in-userstab-editors).